# Is there any way I can combine these two query statements?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a very simple view counter.  Ultimately I will convert to a cronjob view counter/updater, but for now I will just use a mysql update query every time the page refreshes.  I was wondering if there was any way to turn these 2 statements into one, trying to cut down on processing.

PHP:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$q'");  //string is escaped (not shown)
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $views=$row['views']+1;
}
mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET views='$views' WHERE id='$q'");
```

Also, it would be really helpful if you could point out potential security issues if you notice any. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET views=views+1 WHERE id='$q'");
```

This will increase your views by 1.

Comment: what is the "views" in "views+1".  where will this value come from.  don't i need a query to get this value

Comment: This is executed in the database so are saying that the value of "views" should become the sum of the previous values of "views" and 1.  "views" is the previous value in the database.

Comment: that's just the column value. compare it with vars in php (or any other language that is)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to update the view everytime and increment with a value 1 . You can directly do it without select like :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET views=views+1 WHERE id='$q'");
```

This will increment your view .

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @sabari please see my comment above

Comment: @kirby You got the point now right, so do i need to explain :)